# pdfkitのheaderだけが、htmlタグが解釈されず、そのまま出力されます。

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf

pdfkitを用いて、PDFファイルを生成する機能を実装しておりまして、
PDFファイルができるところまではできました。

https://github.com/pdfkit/pdfkit

ただ、共通のheader, footerを入れる際に、htmlタグがそのままでてしまいます。

Controllerの処理は次の通り、記述しております。

レイアウトはslimで書いておりまして、この部分は問題なく、htmlタグが解釈できておりました。

```
def export
  respond_to do |format|
    # .html でアクセスした際は、リダイレクト(show_as_html を true にするため、debug: 1 で)
    format.html { redirect_to action: 'export', format: 'pdf', debug: 1 }
    format.pdf do
      html = render_to_string template: 'layouts/export.html.slim'
      @pdf = PDFKit.new(html, header_left: '<p>hoge</p>')
      @pdf.stylesheets << "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/stylesheets/pdf.css"
      send_data @pdf.to_pdf,
        filename:    "test.pdf",
        type:        "application/pdf",
        disposition: "inline"
    end
  end
end
```

header_leftを追加し `<p>hoge</p>` も出力されているのですが、
headerだけはhtmlタグがそのままでてしまいます。

## 実行環境

```
mac OSX yosemite
pdfkit (0.8.2)
wicked_pdf (1.1.0)
Rails 4.2.7.1
ruby 2.3.1p112
```

## 対策1

エスケープしたりしましたが、ダメでした。

`ApplicationController.helpers.sanitize "<p>hoge</p>"`

http://qiita.com/2or3/items/3f25216663190676a693

## 対策2

Slimがダメなのかと思い次の通りやりましたが、ダメでした。

`@pdf = PDFKit.new('<html><head></head><body></body></html>', header_left: '<p>hoge</p>')`

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/74734

Answer (score 0):

pdfkitのREADMEとコードを検索 `header_left` で検索してみたところ、ヒットするものがありませんでしたので、pdfkitが許容する引数ではないではないかと思いました。

```
PDFKit.new(html, header_left: '<p>hoge</p>')

html = render_to_string template: 'layouts/export.html.slim'
```

export.html.slim で `<p>hoge</p>` を記載するのはいかがでしょうか?

Comment: ありがとうございます。header_leftというものがそもそもない可能性があるっていうことですよね？直接export.html.slimに入れるのも良いのですが、今回のPDF出力はユーザーが入力したデータを動的に出力させるため、人によっては2,3ページにまたがっての出力となります。

その場合におきまして、2ページ目以降をヘッダーの位置に出力させるのが難しいのかなと思いました。


export.html.slimの中でのstyleは効きますので、2ページ目以降も上手くヘッダー位置に出力できるのでありましたら、それでも良いかと思います。